# How come Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has a 32bit iso installer?

Tags: 32-bit, release-management, cd-image

As mentioned in the [Bionic Beaver release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes), Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will not have a 32 bit Desktop Image Installer. But in the [beta 1 release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-budgie/releases/18.04/beta-1/) it has  32bit Desktop Images.

This is little off topic, but I'm confused.

Comment: There was a specific set of reasons for dropping 32-bit from the **U**buntu flavor that did not apply to other flavors. They did **not** drop 32-bit due to ennui.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want a 'clean and basic' iso file of Ubuntu Bionic to be released as 18.04 LTS, you can download a **Ubuntu `mini.iso`** alias Netboot iso file. There are versions for 32-bit as well as 64-bit kernels.

During the development phase (until April 2018) you will find the Bionic `mini.iso` files

- via the [ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/)

  - via 'Bionic Daily'

    - for 'Bionic Netboot i386' (32-bit) and Netboot amd64 (64-bit).

      - 'Link to the download information'

You will find more details and the released `mini.iso` files via this link,

[mini.iso, minimal install, netboot iso](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13211730#post13211730)

You can use the `mini.iso` to install standard Ubuntu as well as the community flavours of Ubuntu. You can also create an Ubuntu Server or a custom system with only some manually selected program packages.

---

But Ubuntu Desktop (standard Ubuntu) and Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS will only be released with 64-bit iso files (for standard PC computers) as described in the answer by @pomsky.

Comment: You said until April 2018. Do you know where to find the post-release mini.iso files? Normally I would look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PC_.28i386.2C_x86.29) but that just points to the same link as yours, which is now out of date (timestamp 2018-04-25 21:23). I also posted a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032853/125475) about this.

Comment: @JonBentley, The `mini.iso` files are not released daily. See this link, [Notice board

debian-installer netboot builds. These are reset every time a new debian-installer is uploaded and not on a daily basis.](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds/171035/testcases)

Comment: I think that one small problem with the mini ISO is that [it doesn't install in UEFI mode according to its help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#mini_system_in_UEFI_mode), which I believe a few 32-bit machines need.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, You are right. The Ubuntu `mini.iso` does not boot in UEFI mode, so it does not install in UEFI mode. You can start from an **Ubuntu Server 64-bit iso file** and (at least with the old style server iso with the debian installer) 'do almost the same thing' as with the `mini.iso`. And this can be done **in UEFI mode** too.

Answer (score 36):

The link provided is for [Ubuntu **Budgie**](https://ubuntubudgie.org/), an official community-maintained 'flavour' which uses the [Budgie desktop environment](https://budgie-desktop.org/home/), not for the "*standard*" Ubuntu image (which uses the [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/) desktop environment).

Ubuntu's developers decided to drop 32-bit image for *vanilla* Ubuntu (in fact it's already dropped, there is no Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit image), but (at least some of the) other flavours [will continue supporting 32-bit systems](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-is-dropping-32-bit-images-but-the-rest-of-the-flavors-will-keep-them-517842.shtml) for now.

---

If you want to get a basic image for Ubuntu 18.04, see the [answer by @sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014230/480481).

Answer (score 5):

For your information [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) has 32-bit installer.

You can visit official website https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/ and choose 32-bit version.

Currently they provide both 16.04.5 LTS and 18.04.1 LTS.

If you need to download specific point release you can visit http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/ .

Comment: On 24 November 2020, the site offered 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Ubuntu MATE 18.04.5 LTS, supported until April 2021.

Answer (score 2):

The announcement was never about the Ubuntu flavours like Ubuntu Budgie, but only about Ubuntu itself. Only the Desktop and Server 32-bit images for Ubuntu will go away.

Even the 32-bit repositories won't go away.

From what I've heard the netboot image will continue to be available for 32-bit (even if they won't be available you can just upgrade from a previous installation of that).