# Is there a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?

Tags: 18.04, 32-bit

I have an older HP netbook and am looking for a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Can you advise if one is available?

Comment: 18.04 (Ubuntu Gnome) Desktop lacks a 32-bit iso for a reason: You may find the 32-bit Ubuntu experience wanting. The 32-bit package still exists, you can build a 32-bit Ubuntu system from the 18.04 Server or Minimal images, and we still provide support for it.

Answer (score 5):

Standard Ubuntu flavour has dropped 32-bit installer for the 18.04 release aka Bionic Beaver (actually since the 17.10 release), but rest of the [Ubuntu flavours](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) still [support  32-bit systems](https://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-is-dropping-32-bit-images-but-the-rest-of-the-flavors-will-keep-them-517842.shtml). You get them from here:

- [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/)
- [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/)
- [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)
- [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/)
- [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads)
- [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/download/)

Alternatively, you can use the Ubuntu mini ISO (refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014230/480481)).

Comment: Do any of the flavors quality for extended support via Ubuntu Advantage?

Comment: Warning: Lubuntu.net is NOT official website of Lubuntu distro. Use `Lubuntu.me`

Comment: This answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You can find 32 bit version is here.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: And from there it's possible to upgrade to 32 bit of 18.04.