# X86 architecture

Tags: 32-bit

I have heard people telling that if you are using 32 bit, it is time to change. Is it true? Do I not get 32 bit for Ubuntu? I do not see x86 with lts support. Can I get medium specification 32 bit distro in buntu?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking.   I have a x86 machine running Lubuntu 19.04 but it's specs mean I wouldn't want to run GNOME on 19.04.  There were options to install x86/i686 (32 bit) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS even though the desktop ISO was not available (flavors did support x86/i686/32-bit).  Xubuntu & Lubuntu produced ISOs up to and including 18.10 but stopped that architecture Dec-2018.  So yes x86/i686/32-bit is still supported, but it's support has fewer options, and with few people using it, the support (particularly install options) have reduced. but you can still upgrade for now.

Comment: Sorry sir for my English, but I cannot find latest Ubuntu x86 support. So I may not get LTS edition?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (desktop) is an example of what is no longer offered.  Yes you can `do-release-upgrade` from 17.10 or 16.04 LTS, but the x86 (32-bit) ISO is not available for install of the desktop.   Most Ubuntu flavors however offered a 32bit desktop (eg. Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Kubuntu etc https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours), or you could still do a x86/i686/32-but network install (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/).  It's still supported, but you have fewer options for install (ie. you can use the network installer to build your own desktop if you really want gnome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127402/is-there-a-32-bit-version-of-ubuntu-18-04-desktop) This duplicate candidate provides even more 32-bit options than the main duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS still supports x86 (i686/32-bit) however it has fewer install options.

The main GNOME desktop is not available as a ISO for example, but if you were using x86 (32-bit) 17.10 or 16.04 LTS (Unity), you can still `do-release-upgrade` to it.

You can still install using the network installer (and thus build a GNOME desktop should you really want it), downloads available at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/

Official flavors however still support x86/i686/32-bit for 18.04 LTS and can be downloaded from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

[image: flavors web page]

Clicking on the Lubuntu option you'll eventually get to this page where that flavor can be downloaded in x86/i686/32-bit
[image: lubuntu 18.04 download options]

Note: I'm using Lubuntu only as an example - most (*if not all*) other flavors also supported 32-bit at 18.04, and Lubuntu & Xubuntu also supported installing x86 for 18.10 installs