# Help installing on pc

Tags: boot

I have acquired some old pcs. I want the newest Ubuntu OS on them.

I have downloaded Ubuntu desktop 18.04.3 desktop amd64.iso and used Rufus, ISO to usb, and cmd line to make a bootable usb on windows vista. None have worked.

The pc that I want to run Ubuntu on is a dell opitplex 760. It’s certainly running windows xp 2002 service pack 3, has 2g memory, 2.5ghz processor and 160gb hard drive. I believe it’s a 32 bit system but not sure.

I have also bought 3 usb sticks and none seem to work. I got the pc once to give me a grub error 15 code but now I can’t get it to show back up. I can restart the system and windows xp works every time.

Please help with the right download and the right settings to make a bootable usb for this system. I would like windows xp off and Ubuntu to take its place.

Comment: Then try i386 iso file: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ Rufus prompts you which method of copying you want to use: dd or iso. I don't remember what it should be, but try both to be sure. Also, what means **none have worked**? When grub error 15 code appears?

Comment: Also make sure you are using bios legacy, not uefi.  With 2GB ram, might want to try lighter versions of ubuntu like lubuntu or xubuntu.  My newer dell I had to google a bit for bios settings to boot/install from USB.

Comment: Thank you both I’ll try the 32 bit downloads with Rufus I have to use Rufus 2.8 because the computer I’m using to write the usb drive is a windows vista once I try I’ll let you know how it comes out thank you

Comment: THANK YOU so I can’t run Ubuntu 18 I had to run Ubuntu 16 on 32 bit thank you everyone! With that being said how can I find out how I can update to the latest os?

Comment: This link should answer, seems to be possible if upgrading.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127402/is-there-a-32-bit-version-of-ubuntu-18-04-desktop.  Should try one of the lighter desktops for better performance on 2GB.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-verify-your-ubuntu-download/14010
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
I use dell optiplex 755's to run everything up to Ubuntu 20.04 (20.04 for testing purposes) and find the write to install media the most common flawed bit (ie. use last link; CD means any mean including thumb-drive)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different [Dell Optiplex 760](https://www.google.com/search?q=opitplex%20760) machines with different CPUs. If you have one with a 64-bit processor, just add RAM and you can run full-up Ubuntu. To find what you have, enter your service tag at the [Dell PC Support Site](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/optiplex-760/drivers), or open a terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 and run `lscpu | grep Architecture`

Without a 64-bit processor you will be limited in your choices when it comes to running full-up Ubuntu with the heavy GNOME3 desktop. However, Ubuntu also offers [flavors with less demanding desktop environments](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) which sill still run Ubuntu apps.

32-bit flavors of 18.04 include:

- [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/)
- [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads/)
- [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) and
- [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).